# How to get the size of an element inside an array?

Tags: .net, f#

I am trying to track down a memory corruption bug and I managed to get most of the way there. It turns out that ManagedCuda's `CudaDeviceVariable` class allocates 4 bytes per `bool` element while I am strongly suspecting that F#'s native arrays to take only 1 byte per `bool` element. The `CopyToHost` function assumes that the source and the target are the same size which causes it to write past the end of the array.

I'd like for the compiler to tell me that the F#'s `bool []` is in fact 1 byte per element so I'd have final proof of that and use it to replace the faulty `ManagedCuda` library function for calculating sizes.

How could that be done?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a bullet-proof indication of the `bool` array element allocation size from comparing the factual addresses of adjacent array elements at run-time:

```
open System.Runtime.InteropServices

let boolarray = Array.zeroCreate<bool> 2

let elemSize = Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(boolarray,1) -
               Marshal.UnsafeAddrOfPinnedArrayElement(boolarray,0)
```

evaluates in fsi to

> ```
> val a : bool [] = [|false; false|]
> val elemSize : nativeint = 1n
> ```

that effectively indicates allocation of 1 byte per element without padding on my system.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `sizeof<bool>` to get `1`

Comment: I knew that, but since arrays elements might be padded in ways ordinary values aren't I want to be extra sure. Or maybe .NET arrays aren't ever padded?